# Texting from iPad to Android device

Tags: ipad, text

Can I send a text message from my iPad (iOS7) to someone with an Android device? (Samsung Galaxy 3).

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it with the native messaging system (iMessage only works only with iOS device).

But you can do it with apps like [Whatsapp](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997?mt=8).

Comment: WhatsApp doesn't work on an iPad

Comment: Threema would be an option.

Answer (score -2):

You can send text by textfree app for iPad